# How to call setTabColor() from onTabChanged?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I wanted to change the background of Android tab widget. So I used this code

```
public static void setTabColor(TabHost tabhost) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
        tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); //unselected
    }
    tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabhost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // selected
}
```

In order to change the color of each tab, I had to implement `onTabChangedListener` on the object of the class `TabHost`.

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new TabHost.OnTabChangeListener() {
            public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            }
        });
```

Now, my question is: how can I call the method `setTabColor()` from `onTabChanged` when I have no `TabHost` object to pass as the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `tabHost` variable `final`, then you can reference it inside of OnTabChangeListener.  Another solution like this would be to make `tabHost` a member variable of your Activity, so you can reference it anytime.

Alternatively, if you are in a TabActivity, you can call [`getTabHost()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html#getTabHost%28%29) at any time.

Comment: I was looking for `getTabHost()`. Thanks!